# Good WPF TreeList control for real time data

Tags: wpf-controls, treelist

I'm looking for a good WPF TreeList control (free or otherwise), that behaves reasonably well with lots of cells changing in real time.
Do you have any recommendations?

ps: By TreeList I mean a grid with hierarchical rows that can be expanded/collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried extensively Telerik's RadTreeList control and Syncfusion's GridTree control.
My assessment is that Telerik's controls are in general better documented and better Architected, but their grid is quite slow doing the initial loading of data, especially with lots of columns. Once ItemsSource is binded the real time update works fast. Therefore if you are going to be switching ItemsSource often I don't think Telerik (as of today) is your grid (e.g. a master detail screen with two grids, one for master records and the other for details... not good because the details grid needs to change everytime the user clicks on a master row)

On the other hand, Syncfusion is very fast for both, loading data and for real time updates. Their documentation is not great though, so you rely on their customer support for answers.

Both Telerik and Syncfusion have very good customer support.

Comment: I should also add: Telerik has paid very good attention to details. With Syncfusion it's very easy to find a corner case that is not displayed with a consistant style...